# Save user input in a variable and use it on all pages

Tags: php, html

As described above I want the user to enter any value like "minutes" in a form and use it on another page to set a timer.
In order to do that I should use php.
I have seen and searched many examples, but I can't find any actual way to use a variable in all of the web pages
One example I ran into, was to use:

```
<?php include"form.php" ?>
```

but it also prints the content on it by default.

Now what I truly want is:

A variable $minutes = 3;
Which will be the default value stored somewhere or maybe even on the form page.
I have a form page on which I take the minutes as input from a user
and on clicking the submit button the value of 
$minutes changes into the value provided by the user.
Now he can change it again and again and again to 2 minutes, 5 minutes etc etc, but I have no way to send it across multiple pages.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

To have access to your variable on every single of your pages you could store your variable in a session :

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['minutes'] = 3;

// rest of your code
```

and you can access it like that :

```
 $_SESSION['minutes']
```

or in a cookie :

```
 setcookie("minutes", 3);
```

which you can access this way :

```
$_COOKIE['minutes']
```

Comment: Note that `session_start();`  must come immediately after `<?php`